# How to search by NearZipCode with C# Twilio API?

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm aware of the InPostalCode search from the docs:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/search-and-buy

But I would like to be able to search by zip code proximity.  When my users use my app to provision a number, I'd like for them to be able to see 30 numbers that are closest to the zip code that they provide (since chances are, their exact zip code won't have any numbers).  Is this possible, or will it be any time soon?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

There is an overload on the ListAvailablePhoneNumbers method that takes an AvailablePhoneNumberListRequest object, which has the InPostalCode property:

```
twilio.ListAvailableLocalPhoneNumbers("US", new AvailablePhoneNumberListRequest() { InPostalCode="60001"});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks :).  Just to be clear - this does a proximity search and not a strict in-postal-code search, as the name suggests?

Comment: Pretty sure this limits any results to within a specific postal code.  If you want proximity (for example, your location is near the edge of an area code boundary), you may want to use lat/long and distance parameters.

Comment: My users don't know their latitude/longitude and it would feel silly (and computationally expensive) to have to go use another service to look that up.  Is there a way to request this feature to be added?  InOrNearZip seems like a pretty common use case.